# Is there an algorithm for finding the approximate nearest neighbour from an extremely large number of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, computational-mathematics, applications

Let's say I have some vector $n$ of length 10, and I also have a bag (i.e. multiset) of 1000 numbers, $m$:

$$n = [0.2, 0.3, 0.0, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0, 0.4]$$

$$m = \{0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 1.0, 0.3, ...\}$$

How can I construct a vector $l$ from the elements of $m$ such that the distance between $l$ and $n$ is minimised? Elements are taken from $m$ without replacement. The specific distance metric doesn't really matter — Euclidean, Manhattan, I'm not fussy.

Obviously, the number of permutations here is extremely large, so brute-forcing isn't an option. Is there an approximate method for finding this vector, even if it's something only moderately better than choosing randomly?

Comment: Greedily: find the closest pair formed by an element of $m$ and a component of $n$. Consume this pair and repeat with what remains... Not optimal but probably good enough.

Answer (score 3):

For the Manhattan distance, you can think of this an an [Assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem): assigning a member of the $m$ to each
index of your vector $n$, where the cost for assigning $m_j$ to index $i$ is $|m_j - n_i|$.  Or for Euclidean distance use the cost $|m_j - n_i|^2$.  Efficient algorithms are well-known.